# Is Kephas.Data some kind of ORM?

Tags: orm, kephas

Digging more through the Kephas Framework I noticed that *Kephas.Data* provides a functionality similar to that of classical ORMs. However, I did not find any kind of documentation about how to connect to databases or, at least, to clarify whether my assumption is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, *Kephas.Data* is an abstraction over data persistence. It can be mapped over typical ORMs, or it can be bound directly to a persistance store, like MongoDB. Here are some starting points:

- Whenever you need access to data, import the *IDataSpace* service through a factory, something like the code below:

```
    public class DataConsumer
    {
        IExportFactory<IDataSpace> dataSpaceFactory;

        public DataConsumer(IExportFactory<IDataSpace> dataSpaceFactory)
        {
            this.dataSpaceFactory = dataSpaceFactory;
        }

        public async Task<> GetDocumentsCountAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (var dataSpace = dataSpaceFactory.CreateExportedValue())
            {
                var documentCount = await dataSpace.Query<Document>().CountAsync().PreserveThreadContext();
                return documentCount;
            } 
        }
    }
```

- Use the `Query<TEntity>()` method to query for entities, using LINQ to shape the data. However, you have to make sure that the underlying infrastructure understands the LINQ you use.
- Use `CreateEntityAsync<TEntity>() : TEntity`, `DeleteEntity(entity)`, `FindAsync<TEntity>(id): TEntity`, `FindOneAsync<TEntity>(linq_expression)` to create, delete, or find an entity.
- Use `PersistChangesAsync()` to persist the changes in memory to the persistence store.

A *DataSpace* can hold multiple *DataContexts*, each *DataContext* being responsible for a dedicated data store. The discrimination is done by entity type.

Each *DataContext* implementation is bound to the specific store. By default, Kephas provides the MongoDB adapter, an Entity Framework adapter being also planned.

A special feature is the integration of *DataBehaviors*, which are invoked upon data or query operations.

For more information please consult https://github.com/kephas-software/kephas/wiki/Architecture-of-data-access and the similar wiki pages.

Comment: I have to take a little time to check this out, thanks!

Comment: One question, though: does the Data component integrate in some way with the Model?

Comment: Yes, it does integrate, but this is an optional feature. Check for this purpose the *Kephas.Data.Model* package.